# CS-Cart - Change login URL in notification email

Tags: cs-cart

I was testing the user account registration system.

When new users sign up for accounts, they are sent a notification email.  The email, by default, includes this line:

```
Login URL: http://mystore.com/
```

The problem is, that's not the login URL.  The login URL is `http://mystore.com/login/`

The URL seems to be generated by this line in the email template (profiles_info.tpl):

```
{if $user_data.company_id}{"?company_id=`$user_data.company_id`"|fn_url:'C':'http'}{else}{""|fn_url:'C':'http'}{/if}
```

But I don't understand how fn_url works (there doesn't seem to be any documentation).  So how can I fix the login URL - or what would be the best way to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this function define in /app/functions/fn.common.php

change:

`{if $user_data.company_id}{"?company_id=`$user_data.company_id`"|fn_url:'C':'http'}{else}{""|fn_url:'C':'http'}{/if}`

to this:

`{''|fn_url:'C':'http'}login/`

Comment: Works great!  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The login url in CS-Cart can be generated this way: `fn_url("auth.login_form")`. The auth controller handles the authentication, within this controller, there is a login_form mode, which will display the login screen for the user.

If you would like to display the link in a Smarty template, you can use this code: `{"auth.login_form"|fn_url}`. This is the proper way, to link the login form, because if you hardcode the `/login/` into the template, and later you would like to use a different URL for the login, or you want to use multi-language SEO URL-s, it will fail.

So the correct code in the e-mail template will look like this:

```
{if $user_data.company_id}{"auth.login_form?company_id=`$user_data.company_id`"|fn_url:'C':'http'}{else}{"auth.login_form"|fn_url:'C':'http'}{/if}
```